# Memoir Headings

Tags: header-footer, memoir

What is the best way to customize the headings at the top of each page in a `memoir` document?  For example, if I want just the page number at the top of every left page, and just the chapter title (say, in italics) at the top of every right page?  What if I don't want any header on left pages, but just the page number as a footer in the corner?

Comment: The best way would be to use [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir)'s header typesetting styles. `:)` This is described in detail in the [`memoir` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) (section **7.2 Page styles**, starting on p 118).

Comment: There is also my PracTeX Journal article about the `memoir` page styles: http://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-2/madsen/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Werner comments, the best way to customize the headers/footers when using `memoir` is to use the features provided by the class itself.

In the following code I created a customized page style to produce your first layout: page number at the top (I chose at the left) of even-numbered pages and chapter title in italics at the top (I chose at the right) of odd-numbered pages; since I didn't make any special provision for the `plain` style, the first page of every chapter will retain the default `plain` style:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\nouppercaseheads
\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{}{\itshape\leftmark}
\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{}{}
\makepsmarks{mystyle}{%
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{}}

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Here are the modifications required in the comments; the headers/footers will now extend to the space reserved for marginal notes; the `plain` style has also been redefined to match the layout for other pages:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\nouppercaseheads
\makepagestyle{mystyle} 
\setlength{\headwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
\makerunningwidth{mystyle}{\headwidth}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\itshape\leftmark}{}{} 
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{}{\itshape\leftmark} 
\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{\thepage}{}{} 
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{}{\thepage} 
\makeatletter
\makepsmarks{mystyle}{%
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{.\ }}
\makeatother

\makepagestyle{plain}
\makerunningwidth{plain}{\headwidth}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\thepage}

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: After reading and experimenting around, I came up with the following (closest version to what I want): `\nouppercaseheads
\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\itshape\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{}{\itshape\leftmark}
\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{}{\thepage}
\makepsmarks{mystyle}{\createmark{chapter}{left}{}{}{}}`

But here the headers on each page say `1Test Chapter`.  What is the best way to get them to say `Chapter 1: Test Chapter` (still in italics)?  Thanks!

Comment: Also, is there a way to get all my headers and footers to be aligned all the way on the left/right of the page, rather than aligned with the left/right of the margin?

Comment: @jamaicanworm: see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks--that's exactly what I was looking for.  However, on the first page of each chapter, the page number at the bottom is still centered instead of off to the side.  Is there a way to change this?

Comment: @jamaicanworm: do you want only the footer on the first page of chapters or also the header?

Comment: @jamaicanworm: see again my updated answer.

Comment: Just the page number (footer) on the first page of chapters--as I see your updated code has done.  Thanks!

Comment: @jamaicanworm: You're welcome!