# Table of contents does not comply with changed running heads in memoir

Tags: memoir, imakeidx

I'm typesetting an e-book using the `memoir` class. I've adapted page style so that the running heads are all set in italics. This works just fine *except* with the running head for the table of contents, bibliography, glossary and the three indices. The list of tables and list of figures, however, do adhere to the default style of italicised text.

So far, unfortunately, I have been unable to get the running heads for the table of contents, etc. to also be typeset italicised.

I have tried to play with the typesetting of the headers based on what I found in the relevant section of the manual, as well as in the answers to several questions on this forum, most notably [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38446/memoir-headings).

I've included a minimum working example where the problem occurs with the table of contents. I'm assuming for now that the problem for bibliography, glossary and indices is fundamentally the same, so I have left those out. I did need a table of contents spanning more than one page, and chapters spanning more than one page though in order to show the problem, hence the `foreach` loop in the code snippet.

EDIT: My assumption is *wrong*. The solution proposed by @esdd (see below) solves my problem for the table of contents, the bibliography and the glossary. It does not, however solve the problem for the indices. I have expanded my MWE to include an index of more than one page.

EDIT 2: @daleif has solved the second half of my problem, which in retrospect should have been a new question, as it is a problem in `imakeidx` rather than in `memoir`. As @esdd has solved the original question, I have marked that answer as the solution. Since @daleif's addition can be very useful for other people with this or similar problems, I've added this explanation and an extra tag for `imakeidx`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
    \makeindex[name=rerum,title=Index Rerum,columns=2,intoc]
    \makeindex[program=truexindy,options=-M texindy -C utf8]

\makepagestyle{ebook} 
\makeatletter
\makepsmarks{ebook}{%
\let\@mkboth\markboth
\def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{##1}{##1}}%
}
\makeevenhead{ebook}% 
{\normalfont\thepage%\ \thepart 
}{\normalfont\itshape\leftmark}{} 
\makeoddhead{ebook}% 
{}{\normalfont\itshape\thetitle}{%\numtoName{\thechapter}\ 
\normalfont\thepage} 
\pagestyle{ebook} 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1-8]

\foreach \n in {0,...,18}{%
\chapter{Another chapter}
\lipsum[1-8]
\index[rerum]{foo}
\index[rerum]{bar}
\index[rerum]{foobar}
\index[rerum]{lipsum}
\index[rerum]{frotz}
\index[rerum]{xyzzy}
\index[rerum]{blorb}
\index[rerum]{snarf}
\index[rerum]{guncho}
\index[rerum]{rezrov}
\index[rerum]{zork}
\index[rerum]{gnusto}
\index[rerum]{frobozz}
\index[rerum]{tinsot}
\index[rerum]{gue}
\index[rerum]{belboz}
\index[rerum]{blorple}
\index[rerum]{snavig}
\index[rerum]{yomin}
\index[rerum]{gurgle}
\index[rerum]{jindak}
}

\backmatter

\printindex[rerum]

\end{document}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mind explaining a bit more what the problem is, perhaps add some images? I still have not figured out what the remaining problem is.

Comment: I think I see your problem, but this is not `memoir` related, `imakeidx` overwrites the `memoir` version of `theindex` env, and this `\nouppercaseheads` no longer applies to it. Memoir uses `\indexmark` to set the headers for indexes, if you redefine that macro to, say write to the log, you'll see that it is never executed. Thus the issue is with `imakeidx`, not `memoir` per se

Comment: I'm writing an answer, the solution is pretty simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `\nouppercaseheads`:

```
\makepsmarks{ebook}{%
  \nouppercaseheads
  \def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{##1}{##1}}%
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makepagestyle{ebook} 
\makepsmarks{ebook}{%
  \nouppercaseheads
  \def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{##1}{##1}}%
}
\makeevenhead{ebook} 
  {\normalfont\thepage}{\normalfont\itshape\leftmark}{} 
\makeoddhead{ebook} 
  {}{\normalfont\itshape\thetitle}{\normalfont\thepage} 
\pagestyle{ebook} 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1-8]
\foreach \n in {0,...,18}{%
  \chapter{Another chapter}
  \lipsum[1-8]
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This solves most but not all of my problem. My table of contents, bibliography and glossary are now typeset with the correct running heads. Unfortunately the running heads for my three indices are still typeset in all caps. I shall have to either update my question and expand the MWE or start a new question. Thank you very much indeed for your help so far!

Answer (score 1):

The index header issue is not `memoir` related but rather the fact that `imakeidx` overwrites `theindex`, thus the `memoir` method for index headers (`\indexmark`) is never executed.

Looking through the `imakeidx` sources we find the following

```
\def\imki@indexheaders{%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\indexname}{\MakeUppercase\indexname}}
```

(it is the only place `\MakeUppercase` is used)

The solution is pretty simple, in preamble

```
\makeatletter
\def\imki@indexheaders{\indexmark}
\makeatother
```

then we execute `\indexmark` from `memoir` and this follows `\nouppercaseheads` (it will by default use `\indexname` which is reset via the `imakeidx` options.

Remember `\nouppercaseheads` should be executed *before* activating the page style.

BTW: your definition of `\chaptermark` can also be done via `memoir` basic methods

```
  \createmark{chapter}{both}{nonumber}{}{}
```

Comment: Thank you, Lars! You are right, of course. I had looked through the imakeidx documentation and sources but hadn't found this yet. Thanks again!

Comment: I've marked this as solving my problem, but I'm now thinking it might be fairer to assign the credit to @esdd as his/her answer solved the question I actually asked. The follow-up problem that arose from that solution should really be seen as a separate question. I'll think on it and may well ending up reassigning it. No offense meant of course.

Comment: @YuriRobbers no problem, I don't really collect points, just want to make sure questions are solved.

Comment: I'm glad. I work the same way myself, though a much smaller part of my time than you. It's good to be aware of potential sensitivities though and I do want to be fair. Thanks again for your help.